# How to test authentication to remote IP address

Tags: authentication, powershell

I have one powershell script that invokes another powershell script.

The first script is invoked with an ip address, which gets passed to the second script. The second script is supposed to return the userId in form Domain\User

The first script uses ProcessStartInfo and Process to get elevated credentials to call the second script

```
# part of first script

$startInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$startInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"
$startInfo.Arguments = "C:\script\second_script.ps1 " 

$startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$startInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$startInfo.CreateNoWindow = $false
$startInfo.Username = Service_Account
$startInfo.Domain = Domain
$startInfo.Password = password 

$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo = $startInfo

$process.Start() | Out-Null


$standardOut = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

$process.WaitForExit()
```

The second script has many try-catch blocks, such as checking whether we can ping the machine, checking whether we can access WMI

```
# part of second

# Can we ping the machine?
try{
    Test-Connection $Sender_IP -count 1 -ErrorAction Stop | out-null
}
catch [Exception]
{
    $userId = "Unknown/CannotPing "
    return $output = "userId=" + $userId
}

try
{
    <#Gather information on the computer corresponding to $Sender_IP#>
    $Win32OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Sender_IP -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [Exception]
{
    $userId = "Unknown/CannotDetectOS "
    return $output = "userId=" + $userId
}
```

The script was unable to access WMI of many IP addresses. And when I was trying to troubleshoot by manually remoting into the IP address with the service account, I was unable to.

Now, I am trying to figure out a way for the script to check whether it can authenticate to the IP address. If the script is unable to authenticate to the IP address, it should throw and exception and not even check whether it can access WMI.

What cmdlets can help with this?

Comment: Not sure, but [get-wmiCustom](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/7bae3d39-c6c3-4a8a-8c98-1b8851bd2cbe) lets you specify a timeout, in case that's of interest.

Comment: @noam ok I will try that out